# maximum modulus principle question

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that f is analytic on a domain D which contains a simple closed curve $\gamma$ and the inside of $\gamma$. If $|f|$ is constant on $\gamma$ then either f is constant or f has a zero inside $\gamma$. how to prove it?

Comment: The answer is basically the title of your question. Suppose $f$ is not constant and has no zero in the interior of $\gamma$. Apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: The case where $f$ has a zero inside $\gamma$ cannot be ignored, as for example $f(z)=z$ has constant modulus on the unit circle centered at the origin (of the complex plane).  The trick is how to exploit the absence of an interior zero.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has no zero inside $\gamma$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is holomorphic on $\gamma$ and inside $\gamma$, and by the maximum modulus principle the minimum of $|f|$ is attained at some $z_0\in \gamma .$ Hence the function $|f|^2 =c =constant$ on $\gamma$ and inside $\gamma$. Therefore the functions $f$ and its complex conjugate $\overline{f} =\frac{c}{f}$ are both holomorphic on $\gamma$ and inside $\gamma$.  But this is impossible unless $f$ is constant.

Comment: For the last step, consider that $f+\overline{f}$ would be a real-valued holomorphic function on the interior of $\gamma$, so the real part of $f$ would be constant (and similarly for its imaginary part).